# Аннотация типов python

Tags: python, типы-данных, аннотации

У меня есть следующий код:

```
 for value in entry_element["value"]:
                for file_id in file_ids:
                    if file_id["old_id"] == value["file"]["id"]: # вот тут ошибка т.к. я запрашиваю доступ по ключу, но оно считает, что value это срока
                        value["file"]["id"] = file_id["new_id"]
```

По аннотации: `entry_element: Union[str, dict[str, Any]`, если я получаю доступ по ключу, то `entry_element: dict[str, Any]`. Значит `entry_elements["value"]: Any`, но когда я прохожу по `value`, которые должны быть `Any`, то оно считает, что `value: str`

UPD:
Пример `entry_element`:

```
{
"id": "01cb3f79-db59-45b1-b614-7ad51c568720",
"name": [
  {
    "locale": "ru-RU",
    "text_value": "test_el"
  }
],
"value": [{"url": "url1"}, {"url": "url2"}],
"enabled": true,
"attributes": {
  "optional": true,
  "default_location": "1.11,2.22",
  "default_zoom_level": 1
},
"created_at": "2022-01-27 16:18:08.411943",
"created_by": "9cc79ddc-ca10-44b2-a431-552904cc99ea",
"description": [
  {
    "locale": "ru-RU",
    "text_value": "some descr"
  }
],
"element_type": "7"
}
```

Comment: кто "оно"? И помните, что аннотации в питоне по сути ничего не значат. Просто сноска. На практике они ни на что не влияют. А типа Any нет. Любой тип данных - Any. И str в том числе.

Comment: @Эникейщик. Оно - PyCharm :) В том-то и дело, что Any - любой тип, но почему-то value определяется как str, а по факту это dict

Comment: Можете привести небольшой но воспроизводимый пример данных для `entry_element`?

Comment: @MaxU Добавил пример в вопрос

Comment: @Prosto_Oleg, если исправить опечатку `Union[str, dict[str, Any]` -> `Union[str, Dict[str, Any]]`, то ошибка/предупреждение у меня не воспроизводится - PyCharm счастлив )

Comment: @MaxU Ой, опечатка только в вопросе. В коде опечатки нет. У меня есть множество типов элементов, и скорее всего какой-то содержит не словарь, а строку/число. Буду искать. Спасибо!